The sign in the Stieltjes transform of the Marchenko-Pastur law
Bai and Silverstein (Lemma 3.11) says the Stieltjes transform of the Marchenko-Pastur law ($\sigma^2=1$) is as follows:
$s(z)=\frac{1-y-z{\color{red}+}\sqrt{(z-1-y)^2-4y}}{2y z}.$
I'm confused that this has a different sign ($\color{red}+$) with the one from Wikipedia:
$s(z)=\frac{1-y-z{\color{red}-}\sqrt{(z-1-y)^2-4y}}{2y z}.$
I think this is because of the square root of a complex number, but not sure why.
